# How to retrieve a list of Objects from AsyncTask, by passing in a parameter?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-room

Using the below statement from my PhoneNumbersDao:

```
    // Retrieve entry/entries by contact ID
    @Query("SELECT * FROM phone_numbers_table WHERE contact_id = :contactId")
    List<PhoneNumber> getPhoneNumbersById(long contactId);
```

How can I create a method in my `AsyncTask` to enter my database asynchronously and retrieve all PhoneNumber objects that match the `contactId` which I pass into it? The code below is what I have so far, but I'm sure where I'm meant to pass `contactId`:

```
private static class SelectPhoneNumberByIdAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<PhoneNumber, Void, Void> {

        private PhoneNumberDao phoneNumberDao;

        private SelectPhoneNumberByIdAsyncTask(PhoneNumberDao phoneNumberDao) {
            this.phoneNumberDao = phoneNumberDao;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(PhoneNumber... phoneNumbers) {
            phoneNumberDao.insert(phoneNumbers[0]);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

I am now calling `observe()` as shown:

```
WorksideDatabase database = WorksideDatabase.getInstance(getApplication());
            PhoneNumberDao phoneNumberDao = database.phoneNumberDao();

            phoneNumberDao.getPhoneNumbersById(contactID).observe(this, PhoneNumber-> {


            });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private static class SelectPhoneNumberByIdAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<PhoneNumber, Void, Void> {

    private PhoneNumberDao phoneNumberDao;

    private SelectPhoneNumberByIdAsyncTask(PhoneNumberDao phoneNumberDao) {
        this.phoneNumberDao = phoneNumberDao;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(PhoneNumber... phoneNumbers) {
        phoneNumberDao.insert(phoneNumbers[0]);
        return null;
    }
}
```

This Async should do one thing (insert new phone number) so change class name to InsertPhoneNumAsyncTask 
And for retrieve the phone numbers you can use LiveData

```
 @Query("SELECT * FROM phone_numbers_table WHERE contact_id = :contactId")
LiveData<List<PhoneNumber>> getPhoneNumbersById(long contactId);
```

then you can observe it into your Activity or Fragment like this

```
getPhoneNumbersById(contactId).observe(this, new Observer<List<PhoneNumber>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable List<PhoneNumber> numbers) {
            //here you access the returned numbers
        }
    });
```

[Check this hope it helps you](https://codinginflow.com/tutorials/android/room-viewmodel-livedata-recyclerview-mvvm/part-5-viewmodel)

Comment: How can I access the list returned by `getPhoneNumbersById(contactID)`? I am planning on showing the contact numbers associated with aspecific contact ID, upon entering that ID's contact card (even if LiveData is overkill for this task, I would like to have a functioning code for now).

Comment: thanks for your help Ahmed. I also created a PhoneNumberViewModel class, as some were saying that the returned `numbers` would be null without it.I believe my format is right, but upon querying the database using `observe()`, my app screen goes blank. It might be the case that LiveData is not what I should be using here..